# I need help fixing vba macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset that is made up of a number of rows and columns e.g.

```
a1 b1
a2 b2
a3 b3
a4 b4
a5 b5
```

I want to write code that will loop through the cells one column at a time calculating an index like this (a2-a1)/(a2+a1). I want the result to be saved to sheet2.

I have used this code but I keep getting an error. It breaks at where I am trying to save the results to sheet2.

I need help to fix this code:

```
Sub Combination()

Dim jCell As Range
Dim kCell As Range
Dim result As Double

Sheet2.Cells.Clear

For Each jCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For Each kCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        result = (jCell.Value - kCell.Value) / (jCell.Value + kCell.Value)

        Sheet2.Cell("result").Value = Sheet1.Cell("result").Value

    Next kCell
Next jCell

End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: And that error would be...?  Also, you calculate `result` and then never use it.  Also also, you're setting yourself up for divide-by-zero errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong (and I'm assuming this is more for learning VBA than for anything practical - so I'll ignore the non-vba ways to do this).

One is that I've never seen syntax like this:

```
Sheet2.Cell("result").Value = Sheet1.Cell("result").Value
```

Another is that your dataset consists of string type data e.g. "a1" b1" - now why would you want to do a mathematical operation with strings? Are you trying to combine them(concatenate them)? - otherwise you will just get nonsense numbers if you do arbitrary mathematical operations with strings.

A third is that you need a way to write the output to sheet two in each row. You probably would want to use a counter to do this. This is an example of a sub that works - I'm not sure if it is what you want to do or if it helps you at all:

```
Sub Combination()

Dim jCell As Range
Dim kCell As Range
Dim result As String
Dim i As Integer
i = 1

Sheet2.Cells.Clear

For Each jCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For Each kCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        result = jCell.Value & kCell.Value

        Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value = result

        i = i + 1

    Next kCell
Next jCell

End Sub
```

Good Luck.